# FTS: Searching across multiple fields 'intelligently'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, full-text-search

I have a SP using FTS (Full Text Search). I want searches across multiple fields, 'intelligently' ranking results based on the weights I assign.

Consider a search on a view fetching data from tables: Book, Author and Genre.

Now, I want the searcher to be able to do: "Ludlum Fiction", "Robert Ludlum Bourne", "Bourne Ludlum", etc.

Unfortunately, the only way I have been able to do that at present is this: http://pastebin.com/fdce11ff

This is pretty bad, because I am manually breaking up the search string. I *know* I am doing this completely the wrong way, but can't figure out the *right* way to search across multiple fields in FTS. Can somebody help please?

Comment: What makes you think the way you do it now is wrong?

Comment: Well, I am having to write the ranking algorithm myself, and would have assumed FTS would have a more optimal one? Also, I am not getting the desired results. For example a search for "Al Pacino" is getting results "Al Something" by "Al Author", rather than "Al Pacino" by "Some guy", if you know what I mean. This is because the word 'Al' is repeated in the book's title, as well as the author field.

Answer (score 0):

On your instance; how is your dictionary setup? You might want to add your authors to your dictionary which will likely solve the al pacino issue (also make sure your authors arent noise words.)

You might get better results from the deep search using a [vector type](http://books.google.com/books?id=wGwVkAt79bEC&lpg=PT284&ots=fukBa3bm6g&dq=full%20text%20search%20vector%20space%20results&pg=PT280#v=onepage&q=full%20text%20search%20vector%20space%20results&f=false) search. We have pushed our users (which are internal staff) the other way toward boolean searches as google would ask for. Robert Ludlum and bourne for example.

Comment: Hi, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875237/full-text-search-noise-words-are-being-searched-for to see the problem I am facing with this.

I have opened another question for that, because I am not sure if it's related.