# Full Text Search: Noise words are being searched for

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, stop-words

I have a database in SQL Server 2008 with Full Text Search indexes. I have defined the Stopword 'al' in the Stoplist. However, when I search for any phrase with the keyword 'al', the word 'al' is still uesd in ranking.

This might be related to the fact that I am breaking up search terms, and reconstructing them. I am then searching across multiple fields and ranking the results: http://pastebin.com/fdce11ff. This functions to break up a search

```
'al hamra'
```

into

```
("*al*" ~ "*hamra*") OR ("*al*" OR "*hamra*")
```

for the Full Text Search.

Imagine this scenario:

Name: 
Al Hamra, Author: Jack Brown, Genre: Fiction
Al Karawan, Author: Al Hanz, Genre: Romance

Now a search for **'al hamra'** will return **'Al Karawan'**, in spite of the fact that **'al'** is in the stoplist. Why is this? I thought stoplists would cause words to lose their weightage?

Answer (score 1):

Noise words are specific to code pages; have you added it to the right one? You can use [sys.dm_fts_parser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280463.aspx) to test it (below) this also might work better than your manual word breaking in the code (or not).

```
SELECT special_term, display_term
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser
  (' "al hamra" ', 1033, 0, 0)
```

Assuming you are using code page 1033. If your noise word is in the code page you expect then it should be visible as a noiseword in the list.

Comment: The query showed 'al' as an exact match.

I discovered that the 'al' was in the English stoplist. So I cleared the stoplist, and re-added 'al' in Neutral. However, now it is not showing when I run http://pastebin.com/m6d9fc5f4. I have confirmed that it is present, because I cannot re-add it (gives an error). 

The query you have mentioned still shows 'al' as an exact match.

Comment: Oh, to clarify, my catalog lists all full text indexes in 'Neutral'.

Comment: Tried changing the language of stoplists and all full text indexes to English. The stoplist now shows using the query http://pastebin.com/m6d9fc5f4, but running your query still shows 'al' as an exact match :(